# nginx not opening index.php

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I'm trying to reach my index.php file on localhost / other-40.umwelt-campus.de
but instead of calling the page it's downloading an empty file..
Even if I downloaded php fpm and configured it.

The file is at: /var/www/html/MyDigitalHome/index.php

Parts of the config file look like:

```
root /var/www/html/;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

server_name _;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        # proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

       # With php7.3-cgi alone:
       #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

       # With php7.3-fpm:
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

}
```

The php file just looks like:

```
<!-- Redirect to MyDigitalHome mainpage-->
<?php
  header('Location: /MyDigitalHome/src/services/overview.php');
  exit;
```

Comment: Check the index and access logs. Perhaps your PHP script is generating empty content. You can use an `index.php` file with a single line `<?php phpinfo();` to test your configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith The index.php is showing the php information. So it should work...

Comment: Your PHP file seems to work fine.

Comment: @RichardSmith There is no "php_errors.log" even if the php.ini is configured so. Also not commented out. So what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirection is broken. You must redirect over HTTP, but instead you point to local file, which means it is a) available only to people having access to that file system (usually just you), b) being accessed by web browser **directly** so no matter how good your nginx config is it will not matter as server is not involved in file access (it can be even down and you will get that file if you have filesystem access).

Comment: How would I do that? Just add "http://other-40.umwelt-campus.de/MyDigitalHome/src/services/overview.php" ?

Comment: you cannot add some random chars and expect it to work. The file must be available for web server, so within configured document root.

Comment: so you must put that file i.e. next to currently served files (say copy into `/var/www/html/MyDigitalHome/` and then redirect to just `overview.php` (or services/overview.php if you want to copy whoile tree)

Comment: The file is at /src/services/overview.php . So I guess that'd be the right path then.